# Elasticsearch Get only those date histograms whose bucket size is greater than given number

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query where I am getting data of last 3 years, month wise and I am also getting the count of months (buckets) in which the data is present. Following is my query :

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "compId": [
                        111,
                        112
                    ]
                }
            },
            "must": {
                "range": {
                    "dateCreated": {
                        "from": "2016-04-01",
                        "to": "2019-03-31",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "grp_company": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "compId"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "data_per_month": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "dateCreated",
                        "interval": "month"
                    }
                },
                "count_buckets": {
                    "stats_bucket": { --> I am getting the count of buckets here
                        "buckets_path": "data_per_month._count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, Now I want to have only those date_histograms whose bucket count is greater than 30. Is it possible in ElasticSearch? If yes, then how?

The above query gives me the following result:

```
{
    "took": 68,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 454566,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "grp_company": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 111,
                    "doc_count": 609014,
                    "data_per_month": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1498867200000,
                                "doc_count": 638
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1501545600000,
                                "doc_count": 512
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1504224000000,
                                "doc_count": 491
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1506816000000,
                                "doc_count": 548
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1509494400000,
                                "doc_count": 504
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1512086400000,
                                "doc_count": 415
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1514764800000,
                                "doc_count": 759
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1517443200000,
                                "doc_count": 98564
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1519862400000,
                                "doc_count": 29185
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1522540800000,
                                "doc_count": 38522
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1525132800000,
                                "doc_count": 22821
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1527811200000,
                                "doc_count": 31076
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1530403200000,
                                "doc_count": 67150
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1533081600000,
                                "doc_count": 13464
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1535760000000,
                                "doc_count": 59498
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1538352000000,
                                "doc_count": 27222
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1541030400000,
                                "doc_count": 46009
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1543622400000,
                                "doc_count": 55696
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1546300800000,
                                "doc_count": 45538
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1548979200000,
                                "doc_count": 49606
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1551398400000,
                                "doc_count": 20796
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "count_buckets": {
                        "count": 21,
                        "min": 415,
                        "max": 98564,
                        "avg": 29000.666666666668,
                        "sum": 609014
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 112,
                    "doc_count": 98564,
                    "data_per_month": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2016-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1472688000000,
                                "doc_count": 3123
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1475280000000,
                                "doc_count": 3156
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2016-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1477958400000,
                                "doc_count": 1489
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2016-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1480550400000,
                                "doc_count": 1948
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1483228800000,
                                "doc_count": 3996
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1485907200000,
                                "doc_count": 2766
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1488326400000,
                                "doc_count": 3869
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1491004800000,
                                "doc_count": 6251
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1493596800000,
                                "doc_count": 2640
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1496275200000,
                                "doc_count": 5541
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1498867200000,
                                "doc_count": 5686
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1501545600000,
                                "doc_count": 6524
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1504224000000,
                                "doc_count": 8351
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1506816000000,
                                "doc_count": 4848
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1509494400000,
                                "doc_count": 4209
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1512086400000,
                                "doc_count": 1092
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1514764800000,
                                "doc_count": 2425
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1517443200000,
                                "doc_count": 336
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1519862400000,
                                "doc_count": 5092
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1522540800000,
                                "doc_count": 1354
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1525132800000,
                                "doc_count": 2022
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1527811200000,
                                "doc_count": 1981
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1530403200000,
                                "doc_count": 1751
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1533081600000,
                                "doc_count": 1705
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1535760000000,
                                "doc_count": 2617
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1538352000000,
                                "doc_count": 2217
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1541030400000,
                                "doc_count": 1734
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1543622400000,
                                "doc_count": 1962
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1546300800000,
                                "doc_count": 2601
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1548979200000,
                                "doc_count": 2573
                            },
                            {
                                "key_as_string": "2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "key": 1551398400000,
                                "doc_count": 2705
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "count_buckets": {
                        "count": 31,
                        "min": 336,
                        "max": 8351,
                        "avg": 3179.483870967742,
                        "sum": 98564
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want only those buckets whose "count" in "count_buckets" is greater than 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you are trying to do is filter the bucket based on the `count_buckets.count` value. If the number of buckets created by `date_histogram` are greater than `30` then the bucket (against `compId`) should be retained else it should be excluded. In other words you want to select a bucket based on a condition. For this you have already added `stats_bucket` aggregation to get the count of buckets. Now this can be used as a parameter for [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html). Bucket selector aggregation exactly does what is required.

Just add the `bucket_selector` aggregation to your query as below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "compId": [
            111,
            112
          ]
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "dateCreated": {
            "from": "2016-04-01",
            "to": "2019-03-31",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "grp_company": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "compId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data_per_month": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "dateCreated",
            "interval": "month"
          }
        },
        "count_buckets": {
          "stats_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "data_per_month._count"
          }
        },
        "bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "bucket_count": "count_buckets.count"
            },
            "script": "params.bucket_count > 30"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what my query was and the solution works perfectly! Thanks a tonne! :)

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to achieve this in Kibana?

Comment: In visualisation?

Comment: Yes in visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `min_doc_count` parameter (having value 30) on terms aggregation as per your requirement. `min_doc_count` is the most efficient way to get the result like this. Even you don't need to use count_buckets in this case, which same one aggregation as well, Follow the code below:

```
...
...
"aggs": {
        "grp_company": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "compId",
                "min_doc_count": 30
            },
            "aggs": {
                "data_per_month": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "dateCreated",
                        "interval": "month"
                    }
                },
                "count_buckets": {
                    "stats_bucket": { --> I am getting the count of buckets here
                        "buckets_path": "data_per_month._count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above aggregation would only return only those buckets which have been found in 30 hits. The default value is 1.

For further understanding you can read the Elastic Official documentation here: [min_doc_count Setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No..I guess you did not understand my question. I want only those 'date_histograms' whose 'bucket size' is greater than 30. For e.g if the date_histogram for a given company has '20' number of elements in bucket (bucket size) then it should be ignored.

Comment: Have you tried the above solution? I think this will return only those histogram that is having 30 or more than that bucket in the list. It won't return those histogram having less than 30 buckets.
I hope this should work.

Comment: Yes I tried, its is not working. I have updated my question. I hope it clarifies my query.